# Создание формы регистрации. Ошибка "Сannot import name 'views'"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток!

**Смотреть UPD2: После правок urls.py появляется ошибка **

При попытке зайти на страницу регистрации выдает ошибку

```
cannot import name 'views'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name 'views'
Exception Location: /home/while1pass/project/smartcms/smartcms/urls.py in <module>, line 3
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
```

Структура проекта

```
 smartcms/
├── db.sqlite3
├── __init__.py
├── login
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── login
│   │       └── login.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── registration
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── registration
│   │       └── registrate.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── smartcms
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Файл url.py, где я импортирую модуль views

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^registrate/$', views.RegisterFormView.as_view()),
    url(r'^login/', 'views.log_in'),
)
```

подскажите, где я допускаю ошибку

Исправление кода на следующий вариант проблему не решает

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^registrate/$', views.RegisterFormView.as_view()),
        url(r'^login/', 'views.log_in'),
    )
```

**UPD1: Изменил файл /smartcms/registration/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^registrate/$', views.RegisterFormView.as_view())
)
```

теперь по адресу localost/registrate/ ошибка

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/registrate/
Using the URLconf defined in smartcms.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, registrate/, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Папка проекта есть в PYTHONPATH

**UPD2: После правок urls.py появляется ошибка**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/registrate

importError at /registrate
cannot import name 'RegistrationForm'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/registrate
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name 'RegistrationForm'
Exception Location: /home/while1pass/project/smartcms/registration/views.py in <module>, line 6
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/home/while1pass/project/smartcms',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

файл /smartcms/registration/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.RegisterFormView.as_view()),
)
```

файл /smartcms/smartcms/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^registrate/', include('registration.urls')),
)
```

файл /smartcms/registration/forms.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = "/login/"
    template_name = "registrate.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

файл views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .forms import RegistrationForm

def registrate(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('Форма верна!')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registrate.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В urls.py вы "говорите" импортировать views, который находится в то же папке, что и urls.py. Судя по вашей структуре это не так.

smartcms/smartcms/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^registrate/', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'^login/', 'views.log_in'),
)
```

smartcms/registration/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^$', views.RegisterFormView.as_view()),
    ...
)
```

Или проще:

smartcms/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from registration import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^registrate/', views.RegisterFormView.as_view()),
    url(r'^login/', 'views.log_in'),
)
```

файл /smartcms/registration/views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = "/login/"
    template_name = "registrate.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Не понял. сейчас у меня в посте представлен /smartcms/smartcms/urls.py. Урлы в приложениях пустые

Comment: вы должны импортировать smartcms/registrate/views.py: from smartcms.registrate import views

Comment: хотя правильнее будет "заинклудить" urls из папки smartcms/registrate. А в нем уже пропусывать url(r'^registrate/$', views.RegisterFormView.as_view()),

Comment: первый вариант не помог, ошибка изменилась на No module named 'smartcms.registrate'.

Comment: исправил файл smartcms/registrate/urls.py. новые ошибки. добавил в пост

Comment: smartcms должен быть в PYTHONPATH

Comment: сделал export PYTHONPATH='/home/user/smartcms/' проблема осталась

Comment: там без smartcms надо было. Поправил в ответе. попробуйте так

Comment: то есть export PYTHONPATH='/home/user'. так? все до папки проекта?

Comment: в файле smartcms/registration/urls.py не надо в урле registrate указывать. Он должен быть в smartcms.smartcms.urls

Comment: в файле smartcms/smartcms/urls.py надо url(r'^registrate/', include('registration.urls'))

Comment: секунду, обновлю пост, проверю

Comment: новая ошибка cannot import name 'RegistrationForm'

Comment: В файле smartcms.registration нет класса RegistrationFormView?

Comment: получается так.

Comment: Покажите registration/views.py

Comment: добавил в пост.

Comment: то что у вас в forms.py должно быть в views.py.

Comment: спасибо, большое! работает, пользователи заносятся в базу